# How to design an app which executes tests on webpage in background, and let the user use his phone normally?

Tags: android, android-service, alarmmanager

I am currently trying to design a particular application and I don't really know how. The app has to run like this.

## What I have to do :

The user launches the application. This action starts something independent of the UI (a Service currently), which has to request a remote server to get test scenario, execute the tests and send results to the same server, even if the UI of the application is not on the screen.

Second constraint : the user chooses, at the beginning, the time between two requests of scenario from the server.

***Example :*** The user starts the app, chooses "do one request of test scenario every 5 min" and after, he can do what ever he wants on his phone. And the app, every 5 min, send a request to get test scenario (not one, but a various number, 50 for example), do the test scenario, and send the results to the server ; and then, wait for the next request.
During this, I think a notification icon in the status bar could be a good thing to access to the UI of the app. With that, when the user feels that the app has done enough tests, he can access to the UI and stop the app.

## What I have already done :

I create an Activity which creates a Service. I also set an alarm with `AlarmManager`, received with an `AlarmReceiver` which calls the Service every X min/seconds/... and starts in the Service a request to the server to get the scenario (the http request is done in an AsyncTask). The service puts a notification in the status bar in its `onCreate()` method. I also managed to parse JSON, send HttpRequest and just technical things like that.

## What my problems are :

I find that the Service stops itself at the end of the `onStartCommand()`. It finishes the method and then go to `onDestroy()` (where I don't put `stopSelf()`), but is the Service really closed ? If yes, how could I managed to have it "up" during all the duration of the application ?

The notification in the status bar just appeared and disappeared with the rythme given by the `AlarmManager`. How could I "stabilize" it ?

If you have already designed an app like that (a mail app, I think, is a good example, which request the mail server every X minutes to check new mail, and send a notification), how can I reach my goal ? To reuse the mail app example : is the service which checks the new mail on the server is always running ?

I really don't know how to design this king of app, so any help is welcome.
Sorry for my bad English. If you want precisions, code of the Service, the Activity, just ask.

Regards

Comment: My "bad" English... I forgot this word. I hope I was understandable in this post.

Comment: Wanted to remark that your english is just fine ;-)

Comment: @Sunny Kumar Aditya : thanks for the spelling mistakes :)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your `Service` is running on the UI thread. You should create a new thread inside your `Service`, where all networking operations will work. So, there is no need in `AlarmManager` - just `wait` X milliseconds inside your `Thread`.

P.S. If you don't know how to create new thread:

```
new Thread(new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
        //your code here
    }
}).start();
```

but I highly recommend you to read about multithreading first.

Comment: Yes, my `Service` is running in the UI thread. I have already an AsyncTask inner class in the Service to do the requests. But how could i make the new thread "talks" to the Service, or the Service commands the new thread ? For example, when the user wants to stop the app, how could i send the stop signal to the Service (this, i know how), and then to the new Thread ?

Comment: @Eriatolc Create class that extends `Thread` (for example `A`). Then in your Service create a field with type of this class. When you want to stop your service just call method of your `Service` that stops the thread first (`A.stop()`) and then stops the service.

Comment: thanks a lot, I'll refresh my mind about multithreading (it's been a long time for me) and try your tips.